# How to post photo using NRGramKit

Tags: iphone, instagram

I try to use NRGramKit.
I download it from
https://github.com/NextRoot/NRGramKit.
But I cannot find method upload photo to Instagram social networking.
Please help me!
Thanks all iOS developer :)

Comment: I don't think anyone has the time to download this project and search for what you need. I suggest you study the code. Or even better consult the person who wrote the project. Try emailing him.

Comment: I have reference http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/. But i cannot find API allows upload photo to Instagram.

Comment: You can reference this application on AppStore https://itunes.apple.com/vn/app/hipstamatic-oggl/id640339204?mt=8. It allows upload photo to Instagram. I don't understand why they can upload photo?

Comment: Here is the developer of this project's web site if you like to to contact him for issues you have with his project. http://nextroot.com